# How do I retrieve HTTP status code from Reachability inside failure block?

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection, http-status-codes, reachability

The main goal is to know which status code is sending me server if it is not available (for ex. 503). Is there are some possibility to retrieve status code inside Reachability failure block, or the only solution is to use NSURLConnection inside Reachability failure block?

I need to do smth like this:

```
internetAvailable = [InternetAvailable reachabilityWithHostName:@"z.example.org"];
    __weak RootViewController *selfCopy = self;
    internetAvailable.reachableBlock = ^(InternetAvailable *reach)
    {
        //All ok
    };

    internetAvailable.unreachableBlock = ^(InternetAvailable *reach)
    {
        if ([reach statusCode] == 503)
        {
            [RootViewController isServerWork];
        }
        else if ([reach statusCode] == 404)
        {
            [RootViewController linkIsBroken];
        }
    };
    [internetAvailable startNotifier];
```